# Cloud Code: Creating a Parse.File from URL

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm working on a Cloud Code function that uses facebook graph API to retrieve users profile picture. So I have access to the proper picture URL but I'm not being able to acreate a Parse.File from this URL.

This is pretty much what I'm trying:

```
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        url: httpResponse.data["attending"]["data"][key]["picture"]["data"]["url"],
        success: function(httpImgFile) 
        {
            var imgFile = new Parse.File("file", httpImgFile);                                             
            fbPerson.set("profilePicture", imgFile); 
        },
        error: function(httpResponse) 
        {
            console.log("unsuccessful http request");
        }
    });
```

And its returning the following:

```
Result: TypeError: Cannot create a Parse.File with that data.
    at new e (Parse.js:13:25175)
    at Object.Parse.Cloud.httpRequest.success (main.js:57:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:842:19)
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was having trouble with this exact same problem right now. For some reason this question is already top on Google results for **parsefile from httprequest buffer**!

The [Parse.File documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.File.html) says

> The data for the file, as 1. an Array of byte value Numbers, or 2. an Object like { base64: "..." } with a base64-encoded String. 3. a File object selected with a file upload control. (3) only works in Firefox 3.6+, Safari 6.0.2+, Chrome 7+, and IE 10+.

I believe for CloudCode the easiest solution is **2**. The thing that was tripping me earlier is that I didn't notice it expects an `Object` with the format `{ base64: {{your base64 encoded data here}} }`.

Also `Parse.File`s can only be set to a `Parse.Object` after being saved (this behaviour is also present on all client SDKs). I strongly recommend using the `Promise` version of the API as it makes much easier to compose such asynchronous operations.

So the following code will solve your problem:

```js
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({...}).then(function (httpImgFile) {
    var data = {
        base64: httpImgFile.buffer.toString('base64')
    };
    var file = new Parse.File("file", data);
    return file.save();
}).then(function (file) {
  fbPerson.set("profilePicture", file);
  return fbPerson.save();
}).then(function (fbPerson) {
  // fbPerson is saved with the image
});
```

Comment: Thanks Paolo, worked well. What about helping in this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33762391/verifying-uniqueness-on-a-batch-save-with-a-huge-amount-of-objects-parse-perfo Valeu! HUE

Comment: You can set an unsaved PFFile on an iOS PFObject, and have it be saved when you save the PFObject.

Comment: This was a lifesaver for me . I was trying to get byte data back to the android client and this worked perfectly. Back on android i extracted the like this.

byte[] imgBytes = Base64.decode(object, Base64.DEFAULT);