# Parse.File Invalid file url

Tags: parse-platform

Does anyone know how to set a simple js Object to Parse.Object's field with type 'file' and save it successfully?

I have a model like

```
{...
 picture: 'file',
 ...
}
```

I upload a file via server side and get an {name,url} object. 
Send it to front-end as JSON.
After that I'm trying to use this JSON as picture

```
{...
 picture: {name,url},
 ...
}
```

via POST request to the server(model.save(params)) but have just

```
{ code: 111,
  message: 'Invalid file url: "http://s3.amazonaws.com/files.parsetfss.com/4d46bc83-d162-4d44-8462-d695f008f787/tfss-8c096482-2b88-4509-a99c-4c99ae57d51d-cat.jpg"' }
```

There is an approach without duplicate pictures like [Cloud Code: Creating a Parse.File from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725285/cloud-code-creating-a-parse-file-from-url)?

Comment: Could you edit your post to turn it into a question instead of a statement?

Comment: @AndrewMorton sure

Comment: Just a notice: how do you get this url?
http://s3.amazonaws.com/files.parsetfss.com/.... ?
For my app the url returned from Parse is just http://files.parsetfss.com/

Comment: @Artyom24 Previous dev did it. Actually, I don't know for what. I tried to remove _s3.amazonaws.com_ but have the same trouble.

Comment: Can you try adding `"__type" : "File",
` something like  ```"picture" : {

"__type" : "File",
"url" : "the_url",
"name" : "the_name"
} ```

Answer (score 0):

Artyom24 was right. 
I've removed **s3.amazonaws.com/** and now everything is ok.